# mod_rewrite not working on Ubuntu with apache2

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, web, apache2

I can't seem to have mod_rewrite working, but it shows it's enabled when I do the phpinfo()
My default file looks like:

> ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I get the 404 error every time I try to access:

```
www.example.com/store
```

Instead of:

```
www.example.com/store.php
```

Any idea what's going on?

This is my current `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Where are your rewrite rules?

Comment: Even if `mod_rewrite` is enable, it will not magically make `store` work from `store.php`

Comment: @vee Is this what you mean? http://pastebin.com/mGhtwAtp

Comment: @Prix http://pastebin.com/mGhtwAtp is my rewrite rules.

Comment: @PlayinCODMC let us know if any of the answer were helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `-MultiViews`, with it enable it will not ignore the directory that does not exist.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## To internally redirect /anything to /anything.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much. All that stress, haha.
Any way to give you points?